# Async / Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke - Antipattern?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I create a option control, that initialized a lot of option pages. I create a async method to do this:

```
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
      _options = new ObservableCollection<IOptionPage>
      {
        new AboutOption(),
        new EnvironmentOption()

      };
    });
  }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My question is, is this a anti pattern? Because I invoke this, I'm not very sure about this. Any suggestions?

AboutOption and EnvirnmentOption both UserControls.

Comment: What's the point of doing this? I mean it looks like it never does anything useful.

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` already allows asynchronous invocation.

Comment: There are multiple anti-patterns present in this code snippet.  But the most severe one is certainly that Task.Run() accomplishes nothing useful since the code forces the code to run on the UI thread again.  Bummer if the window got closed in the mean time, the kind of race bug that only ever occurs when you are not around to see it go wrong.  So just don't bother, it solves nothing and only adds problems.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, that I want to know.